# Which type can i send this function?

Tags: ios, charts, swift3, linechart

I am using [danielgindi/Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) swift framework . I want to use linechart with target line like this;

```
let ll = ChartLimitLine(limit: 6.5, label: "Average")
lineChartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(ll)
```

And it draw target but i want to change color above and below target. I think this function which i should use;

```
open func setCircleColors(_ colors: NSUIColor...){
        circleColors.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        circleColors.append(contentsOf: colors)
}
```

How can i use it? What does means NSUIColor... 
Which type is it? I try to send an array of NSUIColor but it is an error? 
How can i do this?

My all code for linechart;

```
let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: lineDataEntries, label: "price")
        var datasets=[IChartDataSet]()
        datasets.append(lineChartDataSet)
        let linechartdata=LineChartData(dataSets:datasets)
        lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption:.easeInElastic)
        lineChartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
        var colorArray: [NSUIColor] = []

        for data in lineChartDataSet.values{
            if data.y > 6.5{
                 colorArray.append(NSUIColor.red)
                //lineChartDataSet.setCircleColor(NSUIColor.red)
            }else{
                colorArray.append(NSUIColor.green)
                //lineChartDataSet.setCircleColor(NSUIColor.green)
            }
        }
        lineChartDataSet.setCircleColors(colorArray)
        let ll = ChartLimitLine(limit: 6.5, label: "Average")
        lineChartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(ll)
        lineChartView.data=linechartdata
```

Answer (score 1):

An argument shown as `SomeType...` means it is a variadic parameter. This means you can pass 0 or more arguments of the given type. But they need to be passed as comma separated values, not as an array.

```
lineChartDataSet.setCircleColors(NSUIColor.red, NSUIColor.green, NSUIColor.whatever)
```

Comment: Yes. If i have thousands values, this is not correct way. Thanks.

Comment: That's a complaint for the author of the library. You asked a question. I provided an answer.

Comment: No, no you are right. My way is not correct way, i mean.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add or try for variadic parameters. There also one variable `lineChartDataSet.circleColors` where you can set `[NSUIColor]` any no. of colors can be set here. I have tried for `lineChartDataSet.setCircleColors` but its more complicated when your graph grows. I am using swift 3 version for it.

```
let arr: [NSUIColor] = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.yellow]
lineChartDataSet.circleColors = arr
```

This logic works for me fine.